# Paypal adaptive payment result

Tags: c#, .net, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am new to paypal, the following code is my code

```
    ReceiverList receiverList = new ReceiverList();
    receiverList.receiver = new List<Receiver>();
    Receiver secondaryReceiver = new Receiver((Decimal)1.00);
    secondaryReceiver.email = "platfo_1255170694_biz@gmail.com";
    receiverList.receiver.Add(secondaryReceiver);
    Receiver primaryReceiver = new Receiver((Decimal)2.00);
    primaryReceiver.email = "platfo_1255612361_per@gmail.com";
    primaryReceiver.primary = true;
    receiverList.receiver.Add(primaryReceiver);

    RequestEnvelope requestEnvelope = new RequestEnvelope("en_US");
    string actionType = "PAY";
    string returnUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/";
    string cancelUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/";
    string currencyCode = "USD";
    PayRequest payRequest = new PayRequest(requestEnvelope, actionType, cancelUrl, currencyCode, receiverList, returnUrl);
    payRequest.ipnNotificationUrl = "http://replaceIpnUrl.com";

    Dictionary<string, string> sdkConfig = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    sdkConfig.Add("mode", "sandbox");
    sdkConfig.Add("account1.apiUsername", "ryanano89-facilitator_api1.gmail.com");
    sdkConfig.Add("account1.apiPassword", "KNQ6M7MH3SJKVGQ8");
    sdkConfig.Add("account1.apiSignature", "AJ2gHJOSiReCgvozz1y4PVUNExXxA1jzzgOvl4pQaW6Ll2KWgHK6.hd3");
    sdkConfig.Add("account1.applicationId", "APP-80W284485P519543T");

    AdaptivePaymentsService adaptivePaymentsService = new AdaptivePaymentsService(sdkConfig);
    PayResponse payResponse = adaptivePaymentsService.Pay(payRequest);
    object dsa = payResponse.error;
```

Now current what i did is, i used a simple button and assign the above to it. But ended up when i click the button, it doesn't have any paypal lightbox pop up in order to let buyer pay payment. May i know what i still lack of?

Comment: Need to get a look at the raw request and response that results from this code.  My guess is that you're simply not redirecting to PayPal the way you should be.  It won't do that on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up, I just have to get the paykey from the response, and redirect to the url of

```
Response.Redirect("https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=" + payResponse.payKey);
```

and everything will be right to do